# How to connect EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, remote-access

We have our important site on EC2 instance. I have console access, I can switch on/off the machine but cannot RDP that machine. Any idea how can i connect to that machine?
I could connect it earlier I mean last week I connected it and worked on that but this week we are not able to RDP it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could previously connect to it, but now you can't, then something changed. If an EC2 instance is stopped and started **it might receive a different Public IP address**, so start by checking that you are connecting to the right address.

Otherwise, things to check are:

- The instance should be in a **public subnet** (defined as a subnet with a Route Table entry pointing to a NAT Gateway)
- The **Security Group** associated with the instance should be permitting port 3389 (RDP) from your IP address, or `0.0.0.0/0` (but that isn't good for security)
- Try connecting from a **different network** (eg home vs office vs tethered via your phone)